# upload zip file and extract it in node.js. but failor extracting without any error

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, file-upload, ejs

I have a confusing problem (In fact all is well). because [the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-zip) works well in other scenarios and other projects. and my [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) also works great. but now I have a mysterious problem with uploading and extracting.

when it is extracting the zip file, it goes to the end of the function and doesn't run other codes. something like goto. without any error. this is my code:

```
const fsExtra = require('fs-extra');
const extract = require('extract-zip');
static async createProject(id, projectName, planId, projectFile) {
  try {
    const image = await ImageModel.findOne({ where: { name: 'nginx' } });
    const zipExtractPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'static-project-file', projectName);
    const projectPort = await PortScanner.unUsePort(~~(Math.random() * (11000 - 8000 + 1)) + 8000, 11000);
    const htmlPath = path.join(zipExtractPath, 'html');

    // extracting
    await fsExtra.mkdirp(zipExtractPath);
    console.log('this log will be printed');
    await extract(projectFile.path, { dir: zipExtractPath }); // jump from here
    console.log('this log won't');
    await fsExtra.unlink(projectFile.path);
    const files = await fsExtra.readdir(zipExtractPath);
    if (files.length === 1) {
      await fsExtra.rename(path.join(zipExtractPath, files[0]), htmlPath);
    } else if (files.length > 1) {
      await fsExtra.mkdirp(htmlPath);
      await fsExtra.copy(zipExtractPath, htmlPath);
    };
  } catch (error) ( console.error(error) }; // and this catch never catch any error.
}; // to here.
```

note: I try many packages like unzipper, unzipper-async, ADM-ZIP, gunzip-file, node-stream-zip but there is no difference. when I submit the form (just one file upload and two text input) file upload successfully but I can not extract it. I try another zip file but there is no difference.

please don't tell me that my code is wrong, because I copy this code to a new project and then it works. wonderful!

Comment: I assume the missing `{` after the `catch(error)` is just a copy paste error right?

Comment: thanks, @eol. it was a simple mistake. it was not my problem.